# vpn - How to chain two OpenVPN servers

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I know there are plenty of questions on Super User about this topic already out there, but all of them are for more advanced users, or they are unclear to me.

I found on Reddit that you supposedly could do `openvpn --config vpn1.ovpn` and then `openvpn --config vpn2.ovpn`, but I've had no success. I'm pretty sure this type of connection only passes the traffic through `vpn2` and it has no "instructions" to pass it through `vpn1`.

I am aware of the method of connecting to a VPN through a virtual machine, but I'm looking for a method that doesn't involve that.

**Edit:**

I'm trying to connect my computer to a VPN server I don't own, and route the traffic through that one to *another* VPN server I don't own. Basically like this:

MY COMPUTER ----------> VPN1 ----------> VPN2 ----------> Internet

Is this even possible without having another device of your own to route through? I know it's possible to do this on one physical machine using a *virtual* machine, like I mentioned earlier, but is this possible with a single physical device?

**Edit 2:**

One of my config files (with remote IP and certificates censored out):

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote 70.**.**.*** 1279
;http-proxy-retry
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port]
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
#auth-user-pass

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blah blah blah
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>



<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blah blah blah
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>



<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
blah blah blah
...
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
```

The other server config has exactly the same setup except for the remote IP. Even the certificates are the same (I'm not a tech wiz, so I don't know if that's normal or not...)

Comment: To what purpose?  External connections would only see the connections from one physical device, no matter how many permutations that went on internally.  Unless, of course, you were connecting through a VPN to an outside third device.

Comment: Um, I'm not very technical, so I'm not sure _exactly_ what you mean, but I was using an OpenVPN client and noticed that it were having DNS leak problems. I also found a solution; chaining VPNs. Like I said, I'm not a tech wizard, I just use OpenVPN for network connections, and I don't own any of the servers, but I just wanted a VPN to browse the internet anonymously.

Comment: I very much doubt connecting to more VPNs is going to solve any DNS leakage. A correctly configuration VPN will not leak DNS requests.

Comment: I can add one or both of the servers' config files... would that help? Besides, when I connected to a VPN on my host OS and then to a VPN on a virtual machine, I did **not** have leak problems.

Comment: Ah but that’s not the same you see. Yes, you need to use DNS servers that would be routed over the VPN connection.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you mean, but are you saying I will need a separate computer? If that's not what you're saying, can you just give me a guide or something?

Answer (score 0):

For one hop using an interim computer called `interim.host`, use the following procedure,
where I have used the official OpenVPN port number `1194`:

From your workstation:

```
$ ssh -L1194:localhost:1194 user@interim.host
```

From `interim.host`:

```
$ ssh -L1194:localhost:1194 user@remote.host
```

Finally connect your local openvpn client to `localhost:1194`.

You may use this procedure to extend to as many hops as required.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the kind of answer I was looking for. I've added an edit to make this clearer.

Comment: Let me know when your edit is done, what kind of an answer you are looking for.

Comment: Finished the edit. I'm looking for a method to chain the VPNs through one device.